# Magento 2.3 how to get attribute options label by value in block

Tags: magento2.3, attribute-options

I am getting attribute values of an attribute color as 5567, 5568, 5569 etc in block of my custom module.

I want to get the attribute color instead of values as red, blue.

I am getting values as below -

```
$productCollection = $this->getProductCollection();
    foreach ($productCollection as $product) { 

        $colrValue = $product->getColor();

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getAttributeText()` function.

```
 $productCollection = $this->getProductCollection();
        foreach ($productCollection as $product) { 
            $colrValue = $product->getAttributeText("color");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
$productCollection = $this->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) { 
    $product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Have you tried this ? @chanchal